# Simple Frobenius problem without recurrence relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

I am just learning frobenius method in my 'math methods in physics' class. The first problem i am trying to solve is $$ x^2y''-xy'+n^2y=0$$ (where n is a constant).

I know that i have to plug in the maclaurin expansion of y which results in me getting this summation

$$y(z) = \sum_{k = 0}^{ \infty} a_kx^{(k+s)}[n^2-(k+s)+(k+s)(k+s-1)] = 0$$
[
by asserting that $$ a_0 \neq 0 $$ is non-zero i solved for s and got $$ s=1 \pm \sqrt{1-n^2} $$

Now i am stuck on how to continue to get the coefficients a_1, a_2, and so on. I remember seeing an example that solved for a recurrence relation but since every term had the same power of x when we plugged it back in we cant do that method.

How do i continue?

Answer (score 3):

Given

$$\tag 1 x^2y''-xy'+n^2y=0$$

where n is a constant, solve the DEQ by the method of Frobenius.

**Method I** Euler-Cauchy

We see that this is a Euler-Cauchy equation, so lets choose:

$$y = x^r \rightarrow y' = r x^{r-1} \rightarrow y'' = r(r-1)x^{r-2}$$

Plugging this back into $(1)$, yields:

$$x^2(r)(r-1)x^{r-1} - x(r)x^{r-1} + n^2 x^r = (r(r-1) + r + n^2)x^r = 0 \rightarrow r_{1,2} = 1 \pm \sqrt{1-n^2}$$

This gives us the linear combination of a solution as:

$$y(x) = c_1 x^{1 + \sqrt{1-n^2}} + c_2x^{1 - \sqrt{1-n^2}}$$

**Method II** Frobenius Method

Using the Method of Frobenius, we have:

$$\tag 2 y = x^s \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k~x_k$$

This gives us:

$$\tag 3 y' = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+s)~ a_k~x^{k+s-1}$$

$$\tag 4 y'' = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+s)(k+s-1)~a_k~x^{k+s-2}$$

Now, in order to calculate the coefficients, lets set up a table of $x$ powers for each term in the DEQ as:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c} 
\text{} & x^s & x^{s+1} & x^{s+2} & \ldots & x^{k+s} \\ \hline
x^2 y'' & s(s-1)~a_0 & (s+1)s~a_1 & (s+2)(s+1)~a_2 & \ldots & (k+s)(k+s-1)~a_k \\ \hline
-x y' & -s~a_0 & -(s+1)~a_1 & -(s+2)~ a_2 & \ldots & -(k+s)~a_k\\ \hline
n^2 y & n^2~a_0 & n^2~a_1 & n^2~a_2 & \ldots & n^2~a_k \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The total coefficient of each power of $x$ must be zero. If we sum the terms in column $x^s$ for $a_0$, we get:

$$(s^2 -2s+ n^2)a_0 = 0  \rightarrow s^2 -2s+ n^2 = 0 \rightarrow s_{1,2} = 1 \pm ~\sqrt{1-n^2}$$

This equation for $s$ is called the indicial equation and we solve it to find our values of $s$.

Next, if we sum the general column for $a_k$, we get (regardless of substituting $s_{1,2}$:

$$(k^2+2 k s-2 k+s^2-2 s + n^2)~a_k = 0 \rightarrow a_k = 0$$

Since $n$ is a constant.

So, from $(1)$, we have:

$$y(x) = x^s \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n~x_n = a_0 x^s \rightarrow y = c_1 x^{1+\sqrt{1-n^2}} + c_2x^{1-\sqrt{1-n^2}}$$

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Did i calculate s incorrectly? Where exactly did i go wrong?

Comment: I cannot figure out what you did, but you might want to spend some time on these examples http://www.its.caltech.edu/~esp/acm95b/frobenius.pdf. Regards

Comment: I accidently wrote the problem down wrong in the original post. The DE is -xy' not +xy'. So i believe that this method is correct but the s i calculated is correct i think. But this still causes me problems in understanding how to do the problem. I believe your methodology will work again for this new value for s, but i am getting lost trying to connect your last few steps. could you explain a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: I reworked the problem. Please, when you write problems like this, double check them. This is why I stay away from these, because people make a lot of mistakes just writing the problem correctly.

Comment: Thanks so much! and so sorry for the typo, i could have sworn i typed it correctly, i will be more careful in the future.

Could you explan the step where you sum the general column a_n? I dont see how you reduced it to what you got

Comment: We have three terms we are summing. We use one of the values we found from $a_0$ for $s$ when we sum. So, use $s = 1 + \sqrt{1-n^2}$, substitute into those three items in the last column and then simplify them. You would also do the same thing for the other value of $s$. I did them both at the same time. Since we have a zero on the RHS, the $a_n$ term is zero.

Comment: but the constant n under the square root is not the same as the incrementer in the parenthesis. It should be $$ a_k[k^2 \pm k\sqrt{1-n^2}] = 0 $$

how do we show that this implies a_k is zero?

Comment: @aaron: Because the RHS is zero, that does not change anything. Clear?

Comment: why cant $$ k \pm k\sqrt{1-n^2} $$ equal zero? Or is it impossible because of the changing k?

Comment: i see. thanks so much for walking me through this, i feel much better about tackling the other differential equations in the same way.

Comment: @aaron: We have $[...]a_k] = 0 \rightarrow a_k = 0/[...] = 0$. Regards